# Does the term "pour into words" exist?

Tags: phrase-request

Do English/American people use the term "pour into words" to express the act of describing a feeling, a story or anything else what was not in written form before.

So I can't "pour into words" a summary of an article (because it was already written down) but I can "pour into words" my holiday stories (I am the first one who will write it down).

Comment: I have never heard "pour into words", and I can't find a single reference on google. Are you sure you don't mean "put into words"? -- to explain a feeling that you are having.

Comment: You can put feelings or thoughts into words, by writing or talking about it. However, writing or telling a story is not putting the story into words.

Comment: I'm really glad you found my answer helpful, but you may want to wait a little while longer before selecting an answer. This post on meta explains some reasons why: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161

Answer (score 3):

You [pour your heart out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pour-your-heart-out) when you confide your feelings to someone. The expression [put into words](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+into+words) means to express your feelings verbally.

I think you could combine the two idioms and people would somewhat understand that you are pouring your heart out and expressing those feelings in words at the same time, but I haven't come across "pour into words".

Comment: Wouldn't the combination of those two be "Pour your heart into words"? :D

Comment: @MorganFR idiom doesn't need to be literal. You could also "pour your words out".

Comment: @MorganFR Would it be? Yes. Does it sound awkward? Also, yes.

Comment: @ColleenV That sounds equally awkward as Morgan's suggestion...

Comment: @T.J.L. I'm not suggesting that it be used, I'm just saying that you can coin new phrases if they reference idioms that folks are already familiar with and be understood. It can easily backfire though and cause people to think that it's a malapropism and not an intentional mash up, so you probably don't want to make the new one too close to the familiar one.